# Is it possible to manupulate ActivityManager or PackageManager with root permission?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-package-managers

I'd like to manipulate `Intent` routing without modifying the Android platform.

Is it possible to manipulate `ActivityManager` or `PackageManager` if we have root permission (superuser)?

Comment: I made some minor changes to make your question a little easier to read and added some tags that I believe are relevant. Good luck!